# What would be the Sankalpa Mantras if Tarpana should be performed in Bangkok?

Tags: rituals, sankalpa

I am a tamil brahmin from chennai going to live in Bangkok for 3 months. I must do the Amavasya tharpanams. What is the Sankalpam to be followed.that is I am looking for substituion to Baharatha varshe Bharatha kande etc. Kindly suggest me the sankalpam

Comment: It could be 'bangkaka-deshe'

Answer (score 1):

Since you live in Asia, it is still jambu dweepa.

Jambu Dweepa is divided into 9 Varsha:

Bharat Kshetra
Mahavideha Kshetra
Airavat Kshetra
Ramyakwas
Hariwas
Hairanyvat Kshetra
Haimavat Kshetra
Devkuru
Uttarkuru

Bangkok will come under Bharatha varsha, bangkok khande... could be the choice

Comment: Answers on this site should be backed up with proper sources. Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)